# Is there a way to add number inside the JQM icons

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile, jqmobi

I am trying to replace the arrow-l icon with numbers in the JQM for a form page.

here is the fiddle 
[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/d9w4Y/4/)

As you can see in the fiddle I am using `arrow-l` icons what I want to do is some how change these icons to numbers like 1-----2------3----4 .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is possible, but *only* if you create your own icon theme, or use CSS styling for those elements. The default jQuery mobile themes do not contain icons with numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/B33K9/

Just find yourself better looking icons

#### HTML:

```
<div class="ui-block-a"><a class=" center1 ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline ui-icon-one">Button</a><div class="line" style="margin-left:62%"></div>

</div>

<div class="ui-block-b"><a class=" center1 ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline ui-icon-two">Button</a><div class="line" style="margin-right:62%"></div><div class="line" style="margin-left:62%"></div>
</div>
<div class="ui-block-c"><a class="center1 ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline ui-icon-three">Button</a><div class="line" style="margin-right:62%; top:-21px"></div>
    <div class="line" style="margin-left:62%"></div>
</div>
<div class="ui-block-d"><a class="center1 ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline ui-icon-four" data-icon="four">Button</a><div class="line" style="margin-right:62%;top:-21px"></div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.ui-icon-one:after {
    background-image: url('http://secondavenuesagas.com/images/bullets/1.gif');
}

.ui-icon-two:after {
    background-image: url('http://secondavenuesagas.com/images/bullets/2.gif');
}

.ui-icon-three:after {
    background-image: url('http://secondavenuesagas.com/images/bullets/3.gif');
}

.ui-icon-four:after {
    background-image: url('http://secondavenuesagas.com/images/bullets/4.gif');
}
```